# User customizable regex expression for string formatting

Tags: javascript, regex

We have a web-app that allows clients to import some CSV data into our database, e.g. a list of products they sell.

The problem is, we'd like to store their data as-is but let the user specify a custom expression so that when they view the data it looks a bit nicer.

Some imported data might look like this:

```
product_label,quantity
A: Product1- 001,50
A: Product2- 001,80
A: Product3- 001,150
B: Product5- 001,100
```

In this case, the client might want to strip out the prefix **'A: '** and the suffix **' - 001'** in the string **'A: Product1- 001'** so that just **'Product1'** is displayed.

The problem is, every client seems to have a different string format and desired output format.

I was thinking of providing the ability to specify a regex to format the string purely on the client-side using javascript but I'm not sure how I would use this regex and how to allow them to specify grouping or back-references.

Any suggestions on how to let them specify their own format? e.g. something like:

```
match_pattern =  ... // input field text (escaped into a regex)
output_pattern = ... // How to let them specify the output from the match results?
display_string = applyFormatting(string, match_pattern, output_pattern);
```

Comment: Does my answer help at all?

Comment: Your answer is a great start, but if possible I'd like the user to go to the column display settings for _product\_label_ and have a single input for _match pattern_ and a single input for _display pattern_. The match pattern could definitely be a regex with some explicit groupings they write themselves, but is there any built-in mechanism to use the regex-exec grouping array and insert it into their customized display pattern?

Comment: You want the user to enter their own Regex Pattern? Sounds far too complicated for an end user unless they're all senior developers or something. I would simply split it into sections or like I have done below and then allow them to select which sections they want using a simple checkbox.

Comment: We may go for a more visual approach like your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: If my answer has helped solve your problem, please put a nice green tick next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some Regex to split the string up.

```js
// Set the original string
var strOriginal = 'B: Product5- 001,100';

// Settings to specify which parts they want
var bln = [];
bln[0] = true;
bln[1] = true;
bln[2] = false;
bln[3] = false;

// Split the orginal string up
var str = []
str[0] = strOriginal.replace(/([A-Z]\:\s)([A-Za-z0-9]+?)(\-\s[\d]+?)(\,[\d]+)/,'$1');
str[1] = strOriginal.replace(/([A-Z]\:\s)([A-Za-z0-9]+?)(\-\s[\d]+?)(\,[\d]+)/,'$2');
str[2] = strOriginal.replace(/([A-Z]\:\s)([A-Za-z0-9]+?)(\-\s[\d]+?)(\,[\d]+)/,'$3');
str[3] = strOriginal.replace(/([A-Z]\:\s)([A-Za-z0-9]+?)(\-\s[\d]+?)(\,[\d]+)/,'$4');

var strOutput = '';

for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { 
    if (bln[i]) {
        strOutput += str[i] + '<br />';  
    }
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = strOutput;
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```